# AppFabric Notification on timeout

Tags: caching, timeout, appfabric

I have enabled notification on AppFabric and I'm trying to get notified when an item is removed from the cache after the timeout specified during the Add.
Ex :

```
TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,10); 
m_cache.Add(OrderId.Text, order, timeout);
m_cache.AddItemLevelCallback(OrderId.Text,DataCacheOperations.RemoveItem,myCacheLvlDelegate);
```

I put a breakpoint in the "myCacheLvlDelegate" method but it is never reached even after the 10s timeout (test).
For test purpose, I have called explicitly

```
 m_cache.Remove(OrderId.Text);
```

after and then the delegate was called !

So the delegate method is only called if I explicitly call the Remove function but not if the timeout expire...

Do you have a solution to get notify after the timeout (the one specified during the add) ?

I need it because I would like to call a webservice after the timeout to refresh data and cache the result again.

Thank you,

Fabrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is to be reminded at specific intervals to refresh the Appfabric cache items.

You could try using the AppFabric cache in conjunction with the Caching block from the Microsoft Enterprise Library. The caching block provides you with the ability to be notified when the item is about to expire. This though will create two caches.

Store an object identifier in the cache provided by the application block with the necessary timeout interval, while you can "Put" the actual data in the AppFabric cache without a timeout interval. Use the "Put" instead of the "Add" to ensure that you replace the object if it exists else create it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this, as I don't think this sort of thing is what the callback mechanism was designed for. I can see what you're trying to achieve, and I can see how you've arrived at this question, but I think as long as your client uses the cache-aside pattern everywhere you're touching the cache you'll get the effect.

For review, the cache-aside pattern is:

- Check the cache for the desired item
- If the item is NOT in the cache

  - Get the item (from whatever source e.g. database, web service)
  - And put it into the cache
  - Return the item to the caller
- If the item IS in the cache

  - (Cast it to the expected type)
  - Return the item to the caller

e.g.

```
Order order;
// Check to see if the order is in the cache
Object cachedOrder = m_cache.Get(OrderId.Text);

if (cachedOrder == null)
{
    // The order is NOT in the cache, so get it from the web service
    order = OrderWebservice.Get(OrderId.Text);
    // Cache the order for 10 seconds
    m_cache.Add(OrderId.Text, order, New TimeSpan(0,0,10);
}
else
{
    // The order IS in the cache, so cast it
    order = (Order)cachedOrder;
}
// Return the order to the client, whether it's the cached order or the one from the web service
return order;
```

In this way, the cached order will never be more than ten seconds old, because if it times out of the cache, the next caller will get a null result from the cache and call the web service again to get the order from the web service. You'll get the same effect, but as the cache will be filled on demand you should see a lower impact on your server as it won't be spinning up a web service request every ten seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 10 sec was for the example. In real it's more and the call to the webservice to fill the cache is very heavy (10sec) so I cannot wait to have a customer to call the page in order to cache the result of the webservice.

Comment: @PhilPursglove, This approach depends on the relatively small times to produce data to cache. When you cache resource intensive operations output the on-demand cacheing may not be an option, and you would want to have an expiry callback fired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if the question is of deep meaning, but if an item expires in appfabric, the notification will be retrieved after it is expired. Even if it is item level callback or cache level call back.

My code is

```
CustomDataCacheOperations.InsertIntoCache(myTestCache, txtKey.Text, InputTable.Text, 10);    
 ndCacheLvlAllOps = myTestCache.AddItemLevelCallback(txtKey.Text, allCacheOperations, myCacheLvlDelegate);
```

And insert method is

```
public static void InsertIntoCache(DataCache curCache, string Key, object value,int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (curCache.Get(Key) == null)
            curCache.Add(Key, value,new TimeSpan(0,0,timeoutInSeconds));
        else
            curCache.Put(Key, value, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutInSeconds));
    }
```

And it is duely giving the notifications for all operations. The notification for expiration will come only after the item is evicted from memory not when the TTL (time to live) is over. I have confirmed this from Microsoft. you should wait a bit to get notifications.

Comment: how much is a bit? What is the DataCacheOperations enum value in the callback? 
EDIT: IT actually did fire but after about a minute(!) or so of waiting. Not really acceptable in some scenarios.

Comment: 1 minute is expected. Trust me, we had long conferences over this with Microsoft's support personnel. All we got is they are still working on it and the notifications are not real time. They said, "we cannot guarantee the notification esp on time". So if you are going to deploy it in production, think twice.  In our case Notifications were coming after 2-3 min of expiration.